# How do I combine three varchars variables from a database into a single variable in a SQL Command that is embedded at the top of Classic ASP page

Tags: sql, asp-classic

For example, I'm trying to combine "String1" "String2" and "String3" to read as "String1 / String2 / String3". Then I'd like to convert that string to a date as each of my three string variables are month, day, and year saved separately.

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, month + "/" + day + "/" + year), 101) AS ActualDate
```

I actually have a functional page already connected to a database. I'm trying to add additional search features, and for that I need to be able to compare an actual date with search parameters when all I have are three varchars. What I'm looking for is how to convert those three varchars in to one string, and then convert that to a date in the SQL. The code example I used above does not work when added to the SQL statement. I don't' know if it's a simple syntax error, or if this isn't even the correct way to go about making the date.

Comment: Why are you saving dates like that? That's broken. Use single datetime column instead. Even if storing month, day, and year separately has any merit (it doesn't!), you would use an integer type rather than a varchar type.

Comment: And FWIW, that looks like Sql Server code. MySql has it's own set of [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql try looking at the STR_TO_DATE() command. Also you have to use concat() in mysql you cannot use the + operand.

```
STR_TO_DATE(concat(month,'/',day,'/',year), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

EDIT:
If you are using sql server change the "/" to '/' in your original question and it will work.

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server, I didn't realize I added the MYSQL tag to the post. I tried using the single quotes and got the same error.

Comment: Is the above sql call in the asp code or in a stored procedure/function on the sql server? See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21560

Comment: You were right. One of the variables was not a varchar. Had to convert it, then the single quotes worked like a charm.